# ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, port

I'm trying to ssh from mac into ubuntu

this is the error msg I got:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.10 [192.168.0.10] port 22.
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Operation timed out
```

What does it mean?

Comment: what is your ip? do you have a hardware firewall between you? Does the ubuntu firewall accept incoming port 22?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a firewall running on that machine (192.168.0.10) blocking access on port 22. That would be my first guess at least.

Comment: No it is not.  I have checked with ufw. It has "allow" status